# Finding out if there is zero, one or infinite linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I got several questions regarding the quantity of possible Linear Transformation given some vectors:
$$\begin{align}T(1,2,3)&=(1,1,1), \\ T(1,1,1)&=(1,2,3), \\ T(-2,-2,-2)&=(1,0,-1).\end{align}$$

> Is there a single Linear transformation for said $T$?

I tried checking the previous vectors for independence, then checking the image of the transformed vectors..

Comment: And when you checked the vectors for independence, what did you find?

Comment: When i checked independence / dependence between the source, i found alpha = 0 and beta = -2 but when i checked the same for the images i found that alpha must be 2 and beta is -1 (therefore not equal).. im not sure thats the way or if that can tell me something

Comment: I have no idea what these “alpha” and “beta” that you refer to are, but if you found a nontrivial linear combination of the three vectors that’s zero, then if $T$ is linear, that _same_ combination of their images must also be zero. So, you’re probably done.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(-2,-2,-2)=-2(1,1,1)$. But does $T(-2,-2,-2)=-2T(1,1,1)$? If not, that would contradict linearity.

In general, if the vectors are not so nice:

Let's say you want to solve $T(v_1)=w_1,\dots,T(v_k)=w_k$. If there is a linear dependence $v_i=\sum_{j\ne i} c_j v_k$ then you should check if $w_i=\sum_{j\ne i}c_jw_k$. If so, the equality $T(v_i)=w_i$ is completely redundant and you can drop it. If not, you have a contradiction and there are no solutions. Suppose you have not arrived at a contradiction and you're left with all $v_i's$ linearly independent. Then there exists a linear transformation $T$. If the $v_i's$ span the entire input space, then the solution is unique. Otherwise, there are infinitely many solutions.

Now, how can you trim the $v_i's$ into a linearly independent set in an organized way? Put the vectors as the columns of a matrix and row reduce. The pivot columns form an independent set and the other columns tell you the dependences to check.

Comment: That is a very nice hint, ty - but what would you do if the vectors arent so easy to see as a multiplication of a scalar ?

Comment: @Lostdawn I edited my answer to discuss the general case.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can draw up a matrix of the vectors and their images. So for your example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-2&1&1&1\\2&1&-2&1&2&0\\3&1&-2&1&3&-1\\\end{pmatrix}$$
You then do row operations to the whole matrix to simplify the 3 x 3 matrix on the left. E.g. to try to reduce it to lower triangular form. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form

If the LH matrix is invertible then there is a unique solution.

If you obtain a row of zeroes on the LH side then there are no solutions unless the RH matrix also has zeroes in that row.

If all dependencies of the LH matrix are matched by the RH matrix then there are infinitely many solutions.

For your matrix I obtain $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&1&-1\\0&1&-2&1&0&-2\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$
and therefore there are infinitely many solutions.

To complete the possibilities:

**Unique solution**
$$\begin{pmatrix}3&*&*&*&*&*\\0&-5&*&*&*&*\\0&0&3&*&*&*\\\end{pmatrix}$$

**No solution**
$$\begin{pmatrix}3&*&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&0&-5&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: May I ask, if I made the row operation in 2 different matrix and got different "unique solution" does that mean there is no solution ? thanks in advance and thanks for the great reply

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. If you give me a couple of minutes I'll do your example and then you can see if it makes sense.

Comment: sorry I wasnt clear enough - what i mean was, i tried checking dependence between the 3 source vectors and 3 image vectors. I found α and β for both matrices but they aren't equal, does that mean there is no transformation ? also ty for working on my example :)

Comment: OK. So in the example above we see that after simplifying we have Row 3 is $0$ throughout. Infinitely many solutions.